# My DVD drive won't detect any CD media (DVDs seem to work). Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: hp, dvd, cd-drive

I have a similar problem to what is described here:

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/dv7-3079wm-BD-DVD-CD-drive-grinding-sound-won-t-read-CD-R-data/td-p/1211755

I have not tried anything in Windows (yet), but I'm getting desperate. It seems that the drivers need to reinstalled in the case of Windows, but what about Ubuntu?

I'm going to test this with a live USB and post the results, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Output of `sudo hwinfo --cdrom`:

```
> hal.1: read hal dataprocess 18596: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL || !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c line 282.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
32: SCSI 400.0: 10602 CD-ROM                                    
  [Created at block.247]
  Unique ID: KD9E.cT9JzcqA6RE
  Parent ID: w7Y8.+Uo0cjWSIFA
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sr0
  SysFS BusID: 4:0:0:0
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0
  Hardware Class: cdrom
  Model: "Optiarc BD ROM BC-5500S"
  Vendor: "Optiarc"
  Device: "BD ROM BC-5500S"
  Revision: "1.83"
  Driver: "ahci", "sr"
  Driver Modules: "ahci"
  Device File: /dev/sr0 (/dev/sg1)
  Device Files: /dev/sr0, /dev/cdrom, /dev/cdrw, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Optiarc_BD_ROM_BC-5500S, /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-4:0:0:0, /dev/dvd, /dev/dvdrw
  Device Number: block 11:0 (char 21:1)
  Drive status: no medium
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #20 (SATA controller)
  Drive Speed: 16
```

It says here no medium, but I have a blank CD in the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drive laser has failed.  There are different lasers at different wavelengths for cds and dvds, which is why one works and the other not.  You will need to replace the drive, possibly by returning it to the manufacturer if it is still under warranty.

Answer (score 3):

Try blowing on the lens in the multi-dvd tray, or using canned air.

It might have some dust or something. So I would suggest trying that, or cleaning in some safe method first, before going out and purchasing a new drive.